# Get the latest date, with 2 tables being used

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to get the latest data of an item, the data being Item, rank vend_num, vend_item and cost obviously showing the record with the latest date. The data is across two tables, which is where I get stuck I have got as far as below the query below, get join and output the data.

```
SELECT itemvend_all.item, itemvend_all.rank, itemvend_all.vend_num, 
       itemvend_all.vend_item, itemvendprice_mst.brk_cost##1, itemvendprice_mst.effect_date
FROM itemvend_all
INNER JOIN itemvendprice_mst
    ON  itemvend_all.item = itemvendprice_mst.item
    AND itemvend_all.vend_num = itemvendprice_mst.vend_num
WHERE (itemvend_all.rank = '1')
```

.

```
item    rank    vend_num    vend_item   brk_cost##1 effect_date
0100G   1   KUVEUR  NULL    1   04/09/2013
0100G   1   KUVEUR  NULL    2   01/11/2015
0120SQ  1   KUVEUR  NULL    4   04/09/2013
0120SQ  1   KUVEUR  NULL    5   01/11/2015
0120SQ  1   KUVEUR  NULL    6   02/11/2015
```

The output should be, with a few hundred other records below.

```
item    rank    vend_num    vend_item   brk_cost##1 effect_date

0100G   1   KUVEUR  NULL    2   01/11/2015
0120SQ  1   KUVEUR  NULL    6   02/11/2015
```

Any help would be great,

Comment: tag the database your using  like Mysql,sql server ...)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to stackoverflow! Suggest formatting your SQL & expected/actual output as code, to make them easier to read. Also, providing some sample data would help. And as per @rams comment, tag the question with which database you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use windows function `row_number` to get the required output

```
SELECT        t1.* from (
SELECT        ia.item, ia.rank, ia.vend_num, ia.vend_item, im.brk_cost##1, im.effect_date,row_number() over(partition by ia.item, ia.rank, ia.vend_num order by im.effect_date desc) rn
FROM            itemvend_all ia INNER JOIN
                         itemvendprice_mst im ON ia.item = im.item AND ia.vend_num = im.vend_num
WHERE        (ia.rank = '1')) as t1
WHERE RN=1
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much for that. Now to use that on other tables.